# Trying to displace iron from ferrous sulphate heptahydrate using aluminium foil but nothing has happened

Tags: redox, aqueous-solution, home-experiment, extraction

I started by dissolving the sulphate into water and filtering it as I noticed there was a dirty residue lying at the bottom. (I am using ferrous sulphate that is commonly used in gardening.) I then poured this solution into a jar along with torn pieces of tin foil (tin foil being a common name; the foil is made of aluminium). At the start the solution was fairly clear and greenish in colour. A few days later there is no sign of iron collecting at the bottom of the jar and there has been a slight change in colour. The solution is now slightly cloudier and looks more like apple juice. The orange colour makes me think there must be iron oxide being produced. I need to know whether my method for displacing the iron is correct and if elementary iron will be produced.

Comment: No, you can't reduce iron like that, for tin is [less active](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_%28data_page%29) than iron. Tin just sits there and does nothing. Meanwhile, iron is _oxidized_ by air to $\ce{Fe^3+}$.

Comment: Take a look at an activity series for more info.

Comment: Isn't tin foil made from aluminium though?

Comment: Aluminium, however,  is easily passivated in the presence of oxygen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are correct**: Commercially available metal foil is typically made from aluminum, even if it's commonly called 'tinfoil' sometimes. As you say, technically, tin foil is made of tin; aluminum foil is made of aluminum.

**Jannis Andreska is also correct**: The passivating oxide on the aluminum is likely preventing the iron ions from reaching the $\ce{Al^0}$ and swiping their electrons.

**So, you are correct again:** The yellow/orange color you're observing is probably oxidation of the $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ to $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$, by $\ce{O2}$ in the air.

---

**One possible approach to breaking the oxide** would be to connect the foil to the negative terminal of, say, a AA battery, with the positive terminal connected to a junk stainless steel spoon, also submerged.  That might not be enough voltage to break down the oxide film, though; on the other hand, a higher voltage might lead to corrosion of the spoon and the release of iron and other metals into your solution.  May or may not be a problem for your experiment?

Regardless, I would recommend adding some table salt $\left(\ce{NaCl}\right)$ to your solution, both to increase its conductivity and also to introduce chloride, which may help to attack the oxide on the aluminum, in tandem with the applied potential.