Aluminum foil & Iron (III) chloride hexahydrate
When I put an aluminum foil strip into 25mL of 0.4M FeCl3.6H2O I was expecting a single replacement reaction with aluminum chloride forming and iron forming a ppt, instead nothing happened.
A reaction similar to Aluminum reacting with copper (II) chloride to form elemental copper is what I was thinking would happen.
Wondering why not?

Aluminium metal has a tenacious surface layer of aluminium oxide which is unreactive.

I would have thought that the acidity of the iron chloride would suffice to break down the aluminum oxide, much like what you see with copper chloride or copper sulfate (copper sulfate "activated" by the addition of an acid).

Evidently not. Try scratching the surface of the aluminium

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48829/trying-to-displace-iron-from-ferrous-sulphate-heptahydrate-using-aluminium-foil

Or pre-dip the Al foil in conc. aq. NaOH, quickly blot dry (avoiding getting any on your hands!), and immediately drop in FeCl3. NaOH can remove the surface oxide.
